# jQuery - businessHours Plugin, always initiates days as isActive:true while they're false

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-plugins, struts2-jquery-plugin

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin called businessHours
[See Github documentation](https://github.com/gEndelf/jquery.businessHours)

There's an initialise option from JSON array, like this:

```
/* initial data */
var operationTime = [
    {"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null},
    {"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null},
    {"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null},
    {"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"7:15","timeTill":"18:00"},
    {"isActive":true,"timeFrom":"9:00","timeTill":"18:00"},
    {"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null},
    {"isActive":false,"timeFrom":null,"timeTill":null}
    ];

$(selector).businessHours({
    operationTime: operationTime,           // list of JSON objects
    postInit:function() {                   // optional
        // post-init handler
    },
    checkedColorClass: "workingBusinssDay", // optional
    uncheckedColorClass: "dayOff",          // optional
    dayTmpl: " ... template content ..."    // optional
});
```

I'm saving those datas into mysql database via php, but when I'm loading datas, I get the same format:

[image]

I don't get it what am I doing wrong here? Someone may help?
Thanks guys!